# Output term field as custom link to another view with context filter - using term alias

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a site with two content types:

1. Blog posts
2. Forum topics

There is one vocabulary:

- Tags

Both blog posts and forum topics are tagged with this vocabulary.

I have a view (view #1) listing the tags most commonly used **on forum posts**. I want each row/term field to link not to the normal taxonomy term page (which will list not only forum topics but **all content**, including blog posts) but to a separate page view (view #2) that takes terms as a contextual filter and shows **only forum posts** with that term.

This means I need to rewrite the field result in view #2 to be a custom link. I **do not** want to use the term ID token in this custom link; instead, I want to use the term alias, and then somehow catch it in view #2's contextual filter.

View #2's URL is /forum. So, for each term in the "Tags" vocabulary, there should be two usable URLs:

1. /tags/[tag-alias from pathauto>]
2. /forum/tags/[tag-alias from pathauto]

The problem is that I can't trust view #2's contextual filter to convert the [tag-alias from pathauto] URL argument to a term name because pathauto drops punctuation and other characters from term names.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!